# Sine and cosine aren't linearly independent at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that sine and cosine are linearly independent. But at $\frac{\pi}{4}$, sine and cosine are equal. So constants where the first is equal to the negative of the second, result in them canceling out and equaling zero. Thus sine and cosine are not linearly independent for all $x$. What am I not understanding about linear independence?

Comment: You have to differentiate a space of scalars and a space of functions.  Linearly independent as functions means they're independent in the space of functions which means there's no linear combination that works *for all* $x$.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? You might as well have said that the one-element set $\{\text{sine}\}$ is not lenearly independent at $x=0.$

Comment: The vectors $(1,\,0,\,1)$ and $(0,\,1,\,1)$ have that their third components aren't linearly independent. Of course, this doesn't make the vectors dependent - all the components matter. This is precisely the same with a space with functions, where the coordinates are evaluations at points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two functions $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent if there are constants $a, b$, not both zero, such that we have the equality of *functions* $af + bg = 0$. Two functions are equal precisely when they have same values, therefore, $af + bg = 0$ if and only if $af(x) + bg(x) = 0$ for every $x$.

You've demonstrated that for $f(x) = \sin x$ and $g(x) = \cos x$, you can find constants $a$ and $b$ not both zero such that $af(x) + bg(x) = 0$ for $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$, but not *for all* $x$.

What you've shown is that $f(\frac{\pi}{4})$ and $g(\frac{\pi}{4})$ are linearly dependent, which is true. Your error comes from the false assumption that if two functions $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent, then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linearly independent for every $x$. That is false because any two real numbers are linearly dependent (because $\mathbb{R}$ is a one-dimensional vector space). You need to distinguish between linear independence of functions and linear independence of real numbers.

Comment: Well explained. +1